# TabBarIOS in ReactNative not working, items overlapping each other

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

So im making an app and this is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TabBarIOS,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions
} from 'react-native';
//import Styles from  './LayoutStyle.js';

class Layout extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {selectedTab: 'tabThree'}
  }
  setTab(tabId){
    this.setState({selectedTab: tabId})
  }
  render() {
    return(<View style={Styles.Layout}>
      <TabBarIOS>
      <TabBarIOS.Item
      systemIcon='history'
      selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'tabOne'}
      onPress={() => this.setTab('tabOne')}>
      <View>
      <Text>Jure1</Text>
      </View>
      </TabBarIOS.Item>
      <TabBarIOS.Item
      systemIcon='bookmarks'
      selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'tabTwo'}
      onPress={() => this.setTab('tabTwo')}>
      <View>
      <Text>Jure2</Text>
      </View>
      </TabBarIOS.Item>
      <TabBarIOS.Item
      systemIcon='more'
      selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'tabThree'}
      onPress={() => this.setTab('tabThree')}>
      <View>
      <Text>Jure3</Text>
      </View>
      </TabBarIOS.Item>
      </TabBarIOS>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
  Layout: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
  },

  TabBar: {
    backgroundColor: 'grey'
  }
});

export default Layout;
```

Well what i expected was an app where you have a TabBar on the bottom with three different items to choose from and it should look like i would in a native ios app. Well thats not the case, what i get is this:
[image]

Well what should i do? How do i style this item to not overlap? Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding a `flex: 1` style to your `View` containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout style is causing the inner content to get centred oddly, change Layout style to this:

```js
Layout: {
   flex:1,
}
```

Additionally, when trying to draw a scene from the tab clicked you will want to use a render function inside the TabBarIOS.Item object, react native provides some good examples of how to do this in the documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tabbarios.html

I would highly recommend placing a navigator for each object which allows you to have much more control over the scene changes:

```js
    <TabBarIOS.Item
        systemIcon='history'
        title= 'Jure1'
        selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'tabOne'}
        onPress={() => this.setTab('tabOne')}>
        <View style = {{flex:1}}>
            <Navigator
              renderScene={this._renderScene}
            />
        </View>
    </TabBarIOS.Item>
```